# C# Web API, Once live cannot be reached by my website

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api, windows-server-2012, restsharp

I have a MVC Project and a Web API project both using .net 4.6.1

So the MVC project calls the Web API and the Web API returns a status code.

So this works perfectly on my local machine, what I mean by this is:

My MVC website when I debug locally calls the Web API (the Web API is hosted on my windows server in IIS) and the status code is return 'OK' and works perfectly.

However when I put my MVC website live (on the same windows server as the Web API) it fails, the status code returned is 0.

I use RestSharp to make the API call and from what I understand a response of 0 is 'not found'.

I know my questions is a little lacking in detail but this is really all I have to go on as posting the code doesnt really help as it works perfectly locally so I am thinking it is something I am missing in IIS or permissions. Just FYI it is not a IP restriction issue as the Web API is open to all at the moment.

Anyone got any ideas on IIS and Windows server and what I could potentially be missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, response code 0 is not "Not Found" (that's 404), it means a network error occurred or that the server closed the connection prematurely. Without any info about the server and the error logs at the server or the actual response, there's not much we can say about this. You need to do more troubleshooting before this becomes an answerable question.

Comment: Are you sure you add "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" in web.cofig

Comment: Udara - what extra info do you need and I will find out

Comment: Hello, further to the above. The error I am getting is below...

Unable to connect to the remote serverSystem.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have sorted the issue.

I was calling the WEB API using a url e.g. api.domain.co.uk, I had set this up within my DNS however I had failed to add a reference to it in the /system32/etc/hosts file, as soon as I added it in here it worked perfectly.

Thanks for the comments.